# tinyMCE adding p tags and nbsp automatically

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, tinymce

I am creating a CMS whereby users can edit html pages stored on the server using tinyMCE. The source text is loaded into the editor my C# codebehind file by placing it into a text area. When I place a breakpoint here I can see that the source html has not been altered by the C# code. When the text appears in the editor though it automatically adds `<p>` tags with non-breaking spaces between them to the top of the document creating larger and larger spacing each time it's saved, even though I have set `force_p_newlines` and `force_br_newlines` to false. This spacing often can't be seen in the editor (only by viewing the source from the Tools->Source Code drop down) before the document has been saved. Any ideas what could be causing this problem? Code for tinyMCE is as follows:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    height: 600,
    width: 1000,
    force_br_newlines: false,
    force_p_newlines: false,

    skin: 'lightgray',
    plugins: [
     "paste advlist link image lists preview hr anchor pagebreak",
     "searchreplace visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime",
     "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor"
    ],
    toolbar: "save | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | print preview fullpage | forecolor backcolor",
    save_enablewhendirty: true,
    save_onsavecallback: function(){
        var contents = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
        //puts contents into HiddenField
        $("[id$='editorContent']").val(contents);
        //Clicks hidden button to trigger event server-side
        $("[id$='testBtn']").click();
    }
});
```

My tinyMCE is version 4.0.17. If necessary I can also attach a link to one of the html pages I'm using but as they were saved to html from MS Word they're full of irrelevant document properties and largely incomprehensible.

EDIT: I resolved the issue in Chrome where the title of the html page was added to the editor content in between `<p>` tags by using one stylesheet and one head stored in a text file for all the pages and removing the titles and lots of other MSO artefacts from them. As such I have removed all my C# source related to this issue but can paste in back in if it might be relevant to the `<p>` and `&nbsp` issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved by adding the following line `forced_root_block:""`